# return function value to variable

Tags: c#, function, methods, while-loop

I'm trying to understand c# and methods/functions at the moment.
I simply want to have the function `PlayerName()` return a value that can be stored in the variable `playerName`.
I have this piece of code and I don't understand what is wrong.
Without the while-loop, it works. As soon as the while loop is implemented, however, a problem occurs in `return playerName` (Use of unassigned local variable 'playerName'). I don't understand how it is unassigned.

```
namespace methodtest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string playerName = PlayerName();

        }

        static string PlayerName()
        {
            bool notCorrect = true;
            string playerName;
            while (notCorrect)
            {
                Console.Write("Type your name: ");
                playerName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"You typed {playerName}. Continue? 'y'/'n'");
                string correct = Console.ReadLine();

                if (correct == "n")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
                }
                else if (correct == "y")
                {
                    notCorrect = false;
                }
            }
            return playerName;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain further what is the problem you are facing? are you stuck in the while loop? did you try to simply debug your code?

Comment: What is the problem? What result would you expect? What result are you getting? As far as I can tell, the method should return and assign the player-name, but you are not using this for anything. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also, it's bad form to use negative-named booleans.  Just name it `correct`, set it to false initially, and use `while(!correct)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're getting is `CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'playerName'`
The compiler is telling you that you need to give `playerName` an initial value.
You can initialize it with any of the following you seem fit.

`string.Empty` or `""`

`null`

as an example
`string playerName = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - you need to initialize the playerName variable (string playerName = "") or (string.Empty)

Second - You're not displaying the playerName, just assigned the result of PlayerName() to the variable. You need to display the variable.